# After stabilizing a video and rendering it, I have more shake, why?

Tags: video, tracking, movie-clip-editor

I am a Blender newbie, and know that I will have to supply additional info...Please be patient with me :-)

I followed this video by Oliver Villar, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nU8zqn091rM. I am using a 54 second video shot with a phone. The rendered AVI video the image jumps between zooms every second or so.

**EDIT:**
I used a single tracker, placed on the cross on the green parament, to do the 2D stabilization.
The original video is here: https://vimeo.com/229907878 
The stabilized video is here: https://vimeo.com/229907728 
Here is a screenshot of how my compositor is set up:

[image: Compositor Setup]

Let me know of anything else I can provide. And, thanks so much for the help!

Comment: How many tracking points did you use? How many did you use to determine size and rotation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To stabilize such a simple shot you just need a few trackers in the scene.

This is one of those situations where having more trackers is not necessarily better. 4 trackers spread far apart in the picture will do.

Once you track those points you should have enough information to stabilize, you need to select which ones you want to use to determine location and which ones to use for rotation and scale.

A couple of trackers should be enough for location, but I would use all four for rotation and scale.

Then set autoscale and adjust the Max value so that the image is not too cropped.

[image]

You can evaluate the shot by enabling Display Stabilization.

[image]
You will notice that she stabilization is far from perfect, but the remaining motion is due to the rolling shutter in the camera, giving you what is called the "Jello Effect" there is nothing to be done about that in blender...

You are ready to render the shot using your current node setup.

Comment: Thank you! The results are better. But, the shake was only reduced a little. You have put me on the right path to learn. Thanks much!

Comment: To learn about motion tracking look at Sebastian Koenig's series of videos called "Track Match Blend 2"